# Tie user input to a particular row in a query excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a query that has live data coming in. I added a column (not to the query, but to the new table) where the user marks a row for follow up or not. When new data comes in from the query the follow up cell copies the one below it rather than staying blank. How can I make my query and user input work nicely with each other?

Query and Follow Up

[image]

Comment: You've tagged `VBA`, indicating that you should have some code you've tried with this issue.  Please provide as an update to your post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.